# MS Access: View SQL Insert statement for Linked Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'd like to see the SQL Insert statement created by Access from a Form, to a linked MySQL table.

Is there any way to view - or log - the SQL statement that Access creates?

Comment: Have you considered enabling the [general_log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html) on the MySQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative to the server log is to enable the ODBC driver log (aka Trace file).

[5.8 Getting an ODBC Trace File](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-trace.html)

This can severely affect performance, so be sure to turn it off after getting the info you need.